# What does it mean to be memory less for a random variable?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, exponential-distribution

I have seen in class the concept of a memory less random variable, I can write it formally as :

$$ P (X > t + s | X > s) = P(X>t) $$

And I understood the mathematical demonstration for the exponential distribution so that for exemple if $ X = 1 - e^{\lambda x}  $. Then survival function :
$$ P (X > t+s | X > s) = \frac{P(X>t+s,X>s)}{P(X>s)} = \frac{e^{-\lambda (s+t)}}{e^{-\lambda s}} = e^{-\lambda t} = P(X>t)$$

But I don't understand what does it mean for a random variable to be memory-less, intuitvely or visually. In addition, the professor told us that the exponential distribution is the only memory less distribution but I don't understand why, wouldn't a geometric distribution wouldn't be also memory-less ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My favorite example is waiting for a bus at a bus stop.

If the distribution for bus arrivals is "memoryless", it doesn't matter how long you've been waiting, the probability that a bus will arrive 10 minutes from now is the same.

Or think of it a different way: Say that a new person arrives after you've already waited for 10 minutes. The probability that that person will wait for 10 minutes total is exactly the same as the probability that you will wait for *another* 10 minutes.

To put it into the context of your equation, given that you've already waited 10 minutes, the probability that you will wait 20 minutes or more total is exactly the same as the probability that the new person will wait 10 minutes or more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I was wondering if there was a way to "visualize" conditional probability which would explain why, in the case of a memory less random variable, probability of B given A is still B but this cannot be held true for random variables "with a memory".